# Getting a path and appending a filename

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get a path (appdata) and append a filename (smss.dll), and combine these two to form `C:\users\username\appdata\roaming\smss.dll`
I have this already:

```
static char appdata[MAX_PATH+1];
SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(HWND_DESKTOP, appdata, CSIDL_APPDATA, FALSE);

LPCSTR target = "smss.dll";
```

How can I combine these to into one variable?

Comment: This is C code. Have you read upon strcat,?

Comment: You should really be using the W versions, not the A versions. It's 2017.

Comment: Appending a filename to a path has additional semantics that the proposed duplicates ignore. Voting to re-open, even if it needs to be closed as a duplicate of another Q&A.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
static char appdata[MAX_PATH+1];
SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(HWND_DESKTOP, appdata, CSIDL_APPDATA, FALSE);

strcat(appdata, "\\smss.dll");
```

The [strcat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) function appends the right-hand string to the left-hand buffer. It assumes the destination has room for the concatenation to be done. If there is not enough space, it is undefined behavior. Thus it is a good idea to check that there is enough space.

Comment: `strcat` is unsafe and should not be used in modern code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that's why I suggested to check is space remains in the destination first

Comment: Use one of the many safe ways of doing this and you don't need to check.

Comment: Yes you made that suggestion, but instead you offered code that is completely unsafe and broken.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PathAppend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565.aspx) (limited to `MAX_PATH` characters), or [PathCchAppendEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707082.aspx) starting with Windows 8.